# Get RowID on Progress Insert

Tags: sql, progress-4gl, openedge, progress-db

I have a table which doesn't have primary key. I needed to add a primary key to the table so I added a column called 'ID'. I am attempting to use the rowid to insert unique ids into this new column. How would I go about getting the rowid when inserting a new record. This is in a Progress database.

```
INSERT INTO PUB.DETAILS (LASTUPDATED, FORMERVALUE, NEWVALUE, ID) 
VALUES ('09/16/2015', 'NEW ITEM', 'ESISTING ITEM', '?')
```

Comment: If you make it auto incremental than no need to pass its value

Comment: @MeerDeen There's no such thing in Progress databases...

Comment: BTW there is a major 'gotcha' with using ROWID or RECID in a database column; the integrity of those values won't survive a dump-and-load...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Progress databases doesn't necessary have a key. At least not in the "SQL way". The keys (as well as the relations) are defined by the business logic (ie how you use the fields.

Since you seem to be working with a database that's in use it might simply be that you don't need a key - there's some kind of logic there already that does the job?

There is a thing called "sequence" in Progress databases that can be used to increase a value - how to access them using odbc or sql I really don't know.

In Progress ABL (4GL) you would say `NEXT-VALUE(sequence-name)`

[Here's some help about SQL and Progress dbs](http://knowledgebase.progress.com/articles/Article/P183766).

Answer (score -1):

Just set your ID column to autoincrement, so you won't need to know the last inserted one.

Comment: Progress db's don't have autoincrement. At least not to my knowledge - they are not really SQL databases.